# Is it possible to determine the number of magnetic poles inside of an induction motors just by looking at coil windings and their respective phases?

Tags: motor, ac, inductor, induction-motor, asynchronous

This is in regards to a 3-phase induction motor. As far as I understand, if inside of the stator of an induction motor we have 6 windings (each 60 degrees apart geometrically) and opposite windings are of the same phase, then we get 2 magnetic Poles in the resultant magnetic field. If however we have 12 windings (each 30 degrees apart geometrically from each other) and opposite windings again are of the same phase, then we get 4 magnetic Poles in the resultant magnetic field. My question is: If I were to be given a diagram/drawing of the winding configuration (geometrical position) and the phase that each winding has (still assuming 3-phase) then is it possible to get the number of magnetic poles of the resultant magnetic field?